# css / html5 :hover state remains after drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drag-and-drop, hover

I'm using html5's drag and drop functionalities to rearrange dom elements on screen - I attach css behavior to the various states of dragging and dropping when I do this, but the problem I'm experiencing is that the hover state remains even after I've dragged, dropped, and moused out of a DOM element. Here's my code:

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function addDragListeners(){
    $('.segmentListItem').each(function(index){
        $(this)[0].addEventListener('dragstart',handleDragStart,false); //rollover for current
        $(this)[0].addEventListener('drop',handleDrop,false); //drops dragged element
        $(this)[0].addEventListener('dragover',handleDragOver,false); //allows us to drop
        $(this)[0].addEventListener('dragenter',handleDragEnter,false); //rollover for target
        $(this)[0].addEventListener('dragleave',handleDragLeave,false); //sets dragged item back to normal
        $(this)[0].addEventListener('dragend',handleDragEnd,false); //sets all back to normal
    });
}

function handleDragEnter(e) {
        // this / e.target is the current hover target.
        this.classList.add('over');
}

function handleDragLeave(e) {
        this.classList.remove('over');  // this / e.target is previous target element.
}

function handleDragEnd(e){
    $('.segmentListItem').removeClass('over'); //removes the over class on all elements
}

function handleDragStart(e){
    draggedItem = this;
    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
}

function handleDragOver(e) {
    if (e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Necessary. Allows us to drop.
    }
    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';  // See the section on the DataTransfer object.
    return false;
}

function handleDrop(e){
    if (e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation(); 
    }

    if (draggedItem != this) { //MH - swap if we're not dragging the item onto itself

        var draggedIndex = $('.segmentListItem').index($(draggedItem));
        var targetIndex = $('.segmentListItem').index($(this));

        if (draggedIndex > targetIndex){
            $(draggedItem).insertBefore($(this));
        } else {
            $(draggedItem).insertAfter($(this));
        }
    } 

    return false;
}
```

CSS:

```
a { border-radius: 10px; }
a:hover { background: #ccc; }
.segmentListItem { text-align:center; width: 50px; margin-right: 5px; font-size: 16px; display:inline-block; cursor:move; padding:10px; background: #fff; user-select: none; }
.segmentListItem.over { background: #000; color: #fff; }
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Experiencing the thing, and more annoying, when reordering elements via drag & drop, it applies the hover state to the element the moves into the place of the one being reordered.

Comment: It might be worth creating a JSFiddle, always helps :)

Comment: have you tried unbinding the event ? $(this).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave')

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle for this or your HTML?

Answer (score 2):

### Status (six years later)

According to https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=134555 this used to be a bug. However, it must have been fixed in the meantime, as it cannot be reproduce anymore in modern browsers. The only browser where I could still replicate it was IE11.

### Working fix

You can replace the CSS `:hover` with a `.hover` class toggled from JS, in order to better control the hover state:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.segmentListItem a').forEach(function (item) {
  item.addEventListener('mouseenter', function () {
    this.classList.add('hover');
  });
  item.addEventListener('mouseleave', function () {
    this.classList.remove('hover');
  });
});
```

Code snippet below:

```js
function addDragListeners() {
  $(".segmentListItem").each(function(index) {
    $(this)[0].addEventListener("dragstart", handleDragStart, false); //rollover for current
    $(this)[0].addEventListener("drop", handleDrop, false); //drops dragged element
    $(this)[0].addEventListener("dragover", handleDragOver, false); //allows us to drop
    $(this)[0].addEventListener("dragenter", handleDragEnter, false); //rollover for target
    $(this)[0].addEventListener("dragleave", handleDragLeave, false); //sets dragged item back to normal
    $(this)[0].addEventListener("dragend", handleDragEnd, false); //sets all back to normal
  });
}

function handleDragEnter(e) {
  // this / e.target is the current hover target.
  this.classList.add("over");
}

function handleDragLeave(e) {
  this.classList.remove("over"); // this / e.target is previous target element.
}

function handleDragEnd(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".segmentListItem").removeClass("over"); //removes the over class on all elements
}

function handleDragStart(e) {
  draggedItem = this;
  e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "move";
}

function handleDragOver(e) {
  if (e.preventDefault) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Necessary. Allows us to drop.
  }
  e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move"; // See the section on the DataTransfer object.
  return false;
}

function handleDrop(e) {
  if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();

  if (draggedItem != this) {
    //MH - swap if we're not dragging the item onto itself

    var draggedIndex = $(".segmentListItem").index($(draggedItem));
    var targetIndex = $(".segmentListItem").index($(this));

    if (draggedIndex > targetIndex) {
      $(draggedItem).insertBefore($(this));
    } else {
      $(draggedItem).insertAfter($(this));
    }
  }

  return false;
}

// JS fix starts here:
document.querySelectorAll('.segmentListItem a').forEach(function(item, idx) {
  item.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
    this.classList.add('hover');
  });
  item.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
    this.classList.remove('hover');
  });
});
// and ends here. Comment these lines, and uncomment the `a:hover` rule in CSS in order to see the initial code

addDragListeners();
```

```css
a {
  border-radius: 10px;
}


/* a:hover {
  background: #ccc;
} */

.segmentListItem {
  text-align: center;
  width: 50px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: move;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  user-select: none;
}

.segmentListItem.over {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.hover {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li class="segmentListItem">
    <a href="#">test1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="segmentListItem">
    <a href="#">test2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="segmentListItem">
    <a href="#">test3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I can still repro the issue in Chrome v73 in year 2019.

Comment: Two more years later, this still reproduces in Chrome 88

Comment: Ironically, still have this issue in 2022

Comment: 2023 and still counting (has anyone found a fix?)